# Drupal 7 - Multi Step Registration with save on end

Tags: users, forms

I have been looking through some tutorials, but couldn't find what i wanted to accomplish.

The thing i can't find in any tutorial/resource is the ability to save users registration data on the last step.

What i want to accomplish is to display a registration page for users, and the user goes through 3 steps.

- Step 1 - Registration info
- Step 2 - Payment Info
- Step 3 - Save and show custom message

Can some one post some good resource, where it shows how to do this.. Preferably with explanation so i can learn from it.

The tutorials i followed so far were saving after the first submit.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

As a clue, build a module and insert your form inside it, then set your form `['rebuilt']` attribute to TRUE in this way your form is saved in `['storage']` attribute in every step and you can get them via `$Form_state` variable.